# Algebraic integers in cyclotomic field: confusion about index of $Z[\zeta]$ in $O_K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am taking a course in Algebraic Number Theory and trying to understand the proof of the following theorem:

**Theorem**
Let $\zeta$ be a primitive n-th root of unity, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ a cyclotomic field. Then the ring of algebraic integers in this field is $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.

For now I am in the case where $n$ is a prime power, say $n=l^s$ for some prime $l$. Similarly to Neukirch, my professor showed that for any $k$: $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]+l^kO_K$ and I understand this. However he stated without proof that this implies that $[O_K:\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]]$ and $p$ are coprime, which is where my problem lies.

(This statement is important to the proof since he then goes on to show that $[O_K:\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]]$ is a prime power and concludes that it must be equal to $1$, thus proving the theorem.)

I do not really know how to approach proving this implication. Here is an idea, but I do not know if it is helpful:
Assume $l$ divides $[O_K:\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]]$. Then the additive group of $O_K/\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ has order dividing $l$ and thus an element of this order. This means there exists $a\in O_K\setminus\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ with $la\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. This feels as if it should not be possible given $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]+l^kO_K$, however I have not been able to prove it.

I think I understand the rest of the proof, so any help on this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you almost got there: $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]+l^kO_K$ implies that $O_K/\mathbb{Z}[\zeta] = l^k(O_K/\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$, i.e. that the multiplication by $l^k$ (and thus also by $l$) has trivial kernel in $O_K/\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$